# Переопределить страницу добавления в админ-панели Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Мне нужно добавить на страницу js-скрипт, который будет рисовать и удалять HTML-элемент. Нужно, чтобы, когда я выбирал элемент в выпадающем списке, рисовался другой выпадающий список или, наоборот, исчезал. Я знаю, как переопределять страницы в Django, но не могу найти нужную, которая отвечает за добавление новых объектов. Помогите найти её.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете `Django Debug Toolbar`, то вы можете просто перейти на нужную страницу админ-панели и во вкладке шаблоны посмотреть откуда загружается страница.

После того как вы нашли где находится эта страница (наиболее вероятно, что путь следующий `venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html`) :

По сути, вы можете внести изменения прямо в этот файл и это будет работать.

Но обычно для более качественной архитектуры приложения все файлы сформированные `Django` для админ-панели оставляют нетронутыми и делают следующим образом:

1. **В корне проекта** создаем папку `templates`.
2. В этой папке `templates` создаем подкаталог `admin`
3. В файле `settings.py` в переменной `TEMPLATES` в поле `DIRS` прописываем путь к нашему шаблону: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

Теперь, если в этом подкаталоге разместить файл `base_site.html`, то он уже будет переопределять файл, который использует `Django` по дефолту.

**Также дополнительная полезная информация:**

Файл `base_site.html` расширяет файл `base.html` (`{% extends "admin/base.html" %}`), это значит, что в нем вы можете переопределить некоторые стили, которые используются в `base.html` прямо внутри файла `base_site.html`, например подгрузить ваш `css` файл со стилями.

В интернете можно найти много различных ресурсов, которые предоставляют измененный вид админки, который как раз получается за счет переопределения файла стилей `CSS`.

Выглядит это так:

```
{% load static %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/admin.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Этот файл уже помещается в каталоге static вашего приложения, а не проекта.

Подробно со всеми нюансами это написано в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/), если остались вопросы, то советую ознакомиться.